# Probability 6 people 2 tickets

Tags: probability

I've been debating the answer to this problem for a while:

Mr. Starnes and his wife have 6 grandchildren: Connor, Declan, Lucas, Piper, Sedona, and Zayne.  They have 2 extra tickets to a holiday show, and will randomly select which 2 grandkids get to see the show with them.

a) What probability does each grandchild have of getting selected to see the show?

b)Find the probability that at least one of the two girls (Piper and Sedona) get to go to the show.

My confusion is due to the fact that there are two tickets.  Does this allow the sum of the probabilities for each grandkid (1/3) to equal 2 rather than 1?

Any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to B is different than Yohanes. I used permutation.

A) Lets say that we are computing the probability that Connor is selected. This probability equals to 1- P(Connor is not selected) = 1 - 5*4/(6*5) = 1/3

B) Probability of selecting at least one girl equals to 1- P(selecting all boys) = 1 - 4*3/(6*5) = 3/5

Comment: My confusion is due to the fact that there are two tickets. Does this allow the sum of the probabilities for each grandkid (1/3) to equal 2 instead of 1?

Comment: The probability of distinct outcomes of an experiment sums up to 1. In this case, our experiment is giving tickets to 2 people out of 6. Lets write distinct outcomes:

Connor, Declan;
Connor, Lucas;
Connor, Piper;
...

The probability of each outcome is 1/15. We have 15 distinct outcomes so it sums up to one. However, selecting Connor or selecting Declan is not a distinct outcome of the experiment. You can select Connor and Declan at the same time. Therefore, it does not sum up to 1. It is more than 1 because it also includes the intersection. Does it make more sense?